# Headless Craft CSRF

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, headless

I have a site that is using Craft CMS headless and React. There are a few forms that need to post to controllers but I'm not sure how to set up the CSRF tokens and keep it secure.

Can anyone advise me on how to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the craft documentation for this: https://craftcms.com/guides/enabling-csrf-protection#updating-your-javascript it should point you in the right direction.